# I cant ping across Lan?

Tags: cisco, routing, ipv4, network, switching

```
    Current configuration : 2695 bytes
    !
    version 15.1
    no service timestamps log datetime msec
    no service timestamps debug datetime msec
    service password-encryption
    !
    hostname RoUtEr
    !
    login block-for 120 attempts 5 within 360
    !
    !
    enable secret 5 $1$mERr$hx5rVt7rPNoS4wqbXKX7m0
    !
    !
    !
    ip dhcp pool Financa
     network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
     default-router 192.168.10.1
     dns-server 8.8.8.8
    !
    !
    !
    no ip cef
    no ipv6 cef
    !
    !
    !
    username admin secret 5 $1$mERr$hx5rVt7rPNoS4wqbXKX7m0
    !
    !
    license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX15247LE2-
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    ip ssh version 2
    no ip domain-lookup
    ip domain-name ccna.com
    !
    !
    spanning-tree mode pvst
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/0
     no ip address
     ip helper-address 192.168.20.10
     ip nat inside
     duplex auto
     speed auto
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
     description Financa
     encapsulation dot1Q 10
     ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20
     description WorkStation
     encapsulation dot1Q 20
     ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/0.30
     description WorkStation 2
     encapsulation dot1Q 30
     ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/0.40
     description Phone
     encapsulation dot1Q 40
     ip address 192.168.40.1 255.255.255.0
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/0.50
     description CameraRoom
     encapsulation dot1Q 50
     ip address 192.168.50.1 255.255.255.0
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/0.99
     description Native
     encapsulation dot1Q 99 native
     no ip address
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/0.100
     description MGM
     encapsulation dot1Q 100
     ip address 192.168.100.1 255.255.255.0
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/1
     no ip address
     duplex auto
     speed auto
     shutdown
    !
    interface Serial0/0/0
     no ip address
     ip nat outside
     clock rate 2000000
     shutdown
    !
    interface Serial0/0/1
     no ip address
     ip nat outside
     clock rate 2000000
     shutdown
    !
    interface Serial0/1/0
     no ip address
     clock rate 2000000
     shutdown
    !
    interface Serial0/1/1
     no ip address
     clock rate 2000000
     shutdown
    !
    interface Vlan1
     no ip address
     shutdown
    !
    ip nat inside source list 1 interface Serial0/0/0 overload
    ip classless
    ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Serial0/0/0 
    ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Serial0/0/1 10
    !
    ip flow-export version 9
    !
    !
    ip access-list extended sl_def_acl
     deny tcp any any eq telnet
     deny tcp any any eq www
     deny tcp any any eq 22
     permit tcp any any eq 22
    access-list 1 permit 192.168.0.0 0.0.127.255
    !
    no cdp run
    !
    banner motd ^CAuthorized Only^C
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    line con 0
     exec-timeout 5 0
     password 7 0822455D0A16
     login
    !
    line aux 0
     password 7 0822455D0A16
     login
    !
    line vty 0 4
     exec-timeout 5 0
     password 7 0822455D0A16
     login local
     transport input ssh
    line vty 5 15
     exec-timeout 5 0
     password 7 0822455D0A16
     login local
     transport input ssh
    !
    !
    !
    end
```

Switch 1

```
  spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
    spanning-tree extend system-id
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/1
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/2
     switchport trunk native vlan 99
     switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,40,50,99-100
     switchport mode trunk
     switchport nonegotiate
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/3
     switchport access vlan 20
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security maximum 2
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/4
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/5
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/6
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/7
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/8
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/9
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/10
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/11
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/12
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/13
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/14
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/15
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/16
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/17
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/18
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/19
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/20
     switchport access vlan 20
     switchport mode access
     switchport voice vlan 40
     switchport port-security maximum 2
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/21
     switchport access vlan 20
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security maximum 5
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
     switchport port-security aging time 10
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/22
     switchport access vlan 20
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security maximum 5
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
     switchport port-security aging time 10
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/23
     switchport access vlan 50
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security
     switchport port-security maximum 2
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 0060.3EBC.AD37
     switchport port-security aging time 10
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/24
     switchport access vlan 50
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security
     switchport port-security maximum 2
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 00E0.8FA1.5C2E
     switchport port-security aging time 10
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/1
     switchport trunk native vlan 99
     switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,40,50,99-100
     switchport mode trunk
     switchport nonegotiate
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/2
    !
    interface Vlan1
     no ip address
     shutdown
    !
    interface Vlan100
     ip address 192.168.100.2 255.255.255.0
    !
    ip default-gateway 192.168.100.1
    !
    banner motd ^CAuthorized Only^C
    !
    !
    !
    line con 0
     password 7 0822455D0A16
     login
    !
    line vty 0 4
     password 7 0822455D0A16
     login local
     transport input ssh
    line vty 5 15
     password 7 0822455D0A16
     login local
     transport input ssh
    !
    !
    !
    !
    end


S1#
```

Switch2

```
Current configuration : 1998 bytes
!
version 15.0
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname S2
!
enable secret 5 $1$mERr$hx5rVt7rPNoS4wqbXKX7m0
!
!
!
ip ssh version 2
no ip domain-lookup
ip domain-name ccna.com
!
username admin secret 5 $1$mERr$hx5rVt7rPNoS4wqbXKX7m0
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk native vlan 99
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,40,50,99-100
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport trunk native vlan 99
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,40,50,99-100
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 40
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 40
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 40
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan100
 ip address 192.168.100.3 255.255.255.0
!
ip default-gateway 192.168.100.1
!
banner motd ^CAuthorized Only^C
!
!
!
line con 0
 password 7 0822455D0A16
 login
!
line vty 0 4
 password 7 0822455D0A16
 login local
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 password 7 0822455D0A16
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
!
!
!
end
```

Switch 3

```
 version 15.0
    no service timestamps log datetime msec
    no service timestamps debug datetime msec
    service password-encryption
    !
    hostname S3
    !
    enable secret 5 $1$mERr$hx5rVt7rPNoS4wqbXKX7m0
    !
    !
    !
    ip ssh version 2
    no ip domain-lookup
    ip domain-name ccna.com
    !
    username admin secret 5 $1$mERr$hx5rVt7rPNoS4wqbXKX7m0
    !
    !
    !
    spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
    spanning-tree extend system-id
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/1
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/2
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/3
     switchport trunk native vlan 99
     switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,40,50,99-100
     switchport mode trunk
     switchport nonegotiate
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/4
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/5
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/6
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/7
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/8
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/9
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/10
     switchport access vlan 100
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security mac-address 0000.0CC3.26DD
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/11
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/12
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/13
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/14
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/15
     switchport access vlan 10
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security
     switchport port-security maximum 5
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/16
     switchport access vlan 10
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security
     switchport port-security maximum 5
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/17
     switchport access vlan 10
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security
     switchport port-security maximum 5
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/18
     switchport access vlan 10
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security
     switchport port-security maximum 5
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/19
     switchport access vlan 10
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security
     switchport port-security maximum 5
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/20
     switchport access vlan 10
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security
     switchport port-security maximum 5
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 0090.2B84.C7E4
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/21
     switchport access vlan 10
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security
     switchport port-security maximum 5
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/22
     switchport access vlan 10
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security
     switchport port-security maximum 5
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/23
     switchport access vlan 10
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security
     switchport port-security maximum 5
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
    !
    interface FastEthernet0/24
     switchport access vlan 10
     switchport mode access
     switchport port-security
     switchport port-security maximum 5
     switchport port-security mac-address sticky 
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/1
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/2
    !
    interface Vlan1
     no ip address
     shutdown
    !
    interface Vlan100
     ip address 192.168.100.4 255.255.255.0
    !
    ip default-gateway 192.168.100.1
    !
    banner motd ^CAuthorized Only^C
    !
    !
    !
    line con 0
     password 7 0822455D0A16
     login
    !
    line vty 0 4
     password 7 0822455D0A16
     login local
     transport input ssh
    line vty 5 15
     password 7 0822455D0A16
     login local
     transport input ssh
    !
    !
    !
    !
    end
```

[image]

Switch1

```
 S1#show spanning-tree vlan 10,20,30,40,50,99,100
VLAN0020
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    32788
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32788  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 20)
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/2            Desg FWD 19        128.2    P2p
Fa0/3            Desg FWD 19        128.3    P2p
Fa0/20           Desg FWD 19        128.20   P2p
Fa0/21           Desg FWD 19        128.21   P2p
Fa0/22           Desg FWD 19        128.22   P2p
Gi0/1            Desg FWD 4         128.25   P2p

VLAN0040
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    32808
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32808  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 40)
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/2            Desg FWD 19        128.2    P2p
Fa0/20           Desg FWD 19        128.20   P2p
Gi0/1            Desg FWD 4         128.25   P2p

VLAN0050
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    32818
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32818  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 50)
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/2            Desg FWD 19        128.2    P2p
Fa0/23           Desg FWD 19        128.23   P2p
Fa0/24           Desg FWD 19        128.24   P2p
Gi0/1            Desg FWD 4         128.25   P2p

VLAN0099
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    32867
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32867  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 99)
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/2            Desg FWD 19        128.2    P2p
Gi0/1            Desg FWD 4         128.25   P2p

VLAN0100
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    32868
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32868  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 100)
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/2            Desg FWD 19        128.2    P2p
Gi0/1            Desg FWD 4         128.25   P2p
```

Sw2

```
S2#show spanning-tree  vlan 10,20,30,40,50,99,100
VLAN0030
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    32798
             Address     0060.4774.2C6A
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32798  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 30)
             Address     0060.4774.2C6A
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/23           Desg FWD 19        128.23   P2p
Fa0/22           Desg FWD 19        128.22   P2p
Fa0/24           Desg FWD 19        128.24   P2p
Fa0/2            Desg FWD 19        128.2    P2p
Fa0/3            Desg FWD 19        128.3    P2p

VLAN0040
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    32808
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             Cost        19
             Port        2(FastEthernet0/2)
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32808  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 40)
             Address     0060.4774.2C6A
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/23           Desg FWD 19        128.23   P2p
Fa0/22           Desg FWD 19        128.22   P2p
Fa0/24           Desg FWD 19        128.24   P2p
Fa0/2            Root FWD 19        128.2    P2p
Fa0/3            Desg FWD 19        128.3    P2p

VLAN0099
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    32867
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             Cost        19
             Port        2(FastEthernet0/2)
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32867  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 99)
             Address     0060.4774.2C6A
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/2            Root FWD 19        128.2    P2p
Fa0/3            Desg FWD 19        128.3    P2p

VLAN0100
  Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
  Root ID    Priority    32868
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             Cost        19
             Port        2(FastEthernet0/2)
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32868  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 100)
             Address     0060.4774.2C6A
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/2            Root FWD 19        128.2    P2p
Fa0/3            Desg FWD 19        128.3    P2p
```

Sw3

```
S3#show spanning-tree vlan 10,20,30,40,50,99,100
VLAN0010
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    32778
             Address     000A.41CC.655E
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32778  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 10)
             Address     000A.41CC.655E
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/3            Desg FWD 19        128.3    P2p
Fa0/17           Desg FWD 19        128.17   P2p
Fa0/16           Desg FWD 19        128.16   P2p
Fa0/18           Desg FWD 19        128.18   P2p
Fa0/19           Desg FWD 19        128.19   P2p
Fa0/15           Desg FWD 19        128.15   P2p
Fa0/20           Desg FWD 19        128.20   P2p
Fa0/22           Desg FWD 19        128.22   P2p
Fa0/21           Desg FWD 19        128.21   P2p
Fa0/24           Desg FWD 19        128.24   P2p
Fa0/23           Desg FWD 19        128.23   P2p

VLAN0099
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    32867
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             Cost        38
             Port        3(FastEthernet0/3)
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32867  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 99)
             Address     000A.41CC.655E
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/3            Root FWD 19        128.3    P2p

VLAN0100
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    32868
             Address     0002.1775.D22D
             Cost        38
             Port        3(FastEthernet0/3)
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32868  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 100)
             Address     000A.41CC.655E
             Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
             Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/3            Root FWD 19        128.3    P2p
Fa0/10           Desg FWD 19        128.10   P2p

S3#
```

Comment: Please be specific in what you are testing and what the results are.

Comment: @TeunVink can you help me pls, where could be the problem

Comment: You’re not describing a problem, you’re posting configurations. Please be specific in what is not working, what output/error you get and what you tried to fix it. Which IP addresses cannot ping each other?

Comment: I'm trying to ping vlans on switch 2 and 3 with each other, i looked the configuration on trunk ports

Comment: @TeunVink Pc from vlan 10 cant ping pc on pc on vlan 20 , 50 and pc on vlan 20 cant ping pc on vl 50

Comment: On switch 1, type `show spanning-tree vlan x`, where X is 10,20,30,40,100.  Make sure all ports are in the `FWD` State

Comment: Fa0/2            Desg FWD 19        128.2    P2p
Fa0/20           Desg FWD 19        128.20   P2p
Gi0/1            Desg FWD 4         128.25   p2p this description is showed , but im not understanding

Comment: all ports are desg and in fwd state

Comment: Same on sw 2 and 3?

Comment: i just post the show spanning-tree vlan for each swich

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing VLANs on your switches.   For example, switch 1 is missing VLANs 10 and 30. The others are missing VLANs as well.

You can add then using the global command

```
Vlan 10
Name abc
```